# watch file size on linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, watch

I want to watch the growing size of a single file, so i use this command:

```
texai@maelstrom ~$ ls -lh club_prod.sql | awk '{print $5}'
116M
```

Now I want to watch that result each 5 seconds so:

```
texai@maelstrom ~$ watch -n 5 ls -lh club_prod.sql | awk '{print $5}'
```

but this command doesn't return any result

Comment: Perhaps this question is a candidate for SuperUser.

Comment: Uh, using `ls` like this is a bad idea.

Comment: Using `watch` is not in the same class as parsing within a script... although I admit in my case I would not filter the output of `ls -l` at all when using `watch` with it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're piping the output of `watch` into `awk`.  If you simplify your command line, what you have is:

```
 watch <some arguments> | awk '{print $5}'
```

That's not what you want.  Try:

```
watch -n 5 "ls -lh club_prod.sql | awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Comment: watch -n 5 "ls -lh acro | awk '{print \$5}' >> acro_size.txt" works for me, when I do it like above it only shows the size one time? (acro is just my test file)

Comment: Hmm, works for me as written.  If I change the size of the file, the display updates every 5 seconds.  Your example in the comment above appears to be redirecting the output from awk to a file...which means you're hardly benefiting from using `watch`, which is meant as a display tool.

Comment: Aha, now I see, it worked for me too (probably), only I expected to get I list, not an update of the entire screen. If you would like to do it to a file as I did, there is probably a better command for just repeating without showing. My mistake.

Comment: `while :; do ls -lh club_prod.sql >> acro_size.txt; sleep 60; done`

Comment: Why use `ls`/`awk` and piping, when there is a single command `du` for it?

Comment: I was answering the question of why the `watch` statement wasn't working.  There are certainly more effective ways of getting at the size of a file.

Answer (score 50):

```
watch -n 5 "du -h club_prod.sql"
```

Comment: This works well on directory with subdirectories psql dumps with the -s flag:

```watch -n 5 "du -sh directory_with_subdirectories/"```

Answer (score 24):

Not exactly related, but if you want to monitor growth rate of some file, you could use following command:

`tail -f yourfile.txt | pv > /dev/null`

- `tail -f` - outputs data appended to file
- `pv` - measures data flow through pipe
- `> /dev/null` - standard output gets discarded

*Note: sometimes `pv` may be not preinstalled*

I hope this will help somebody :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote the pipeline so that it is done *within* `watch`.

```
watch -n 5 "ls -lh club_prod.sql | awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Note also the `\` added to `\$5` because the outer quotes are now double quotes, in which `$`-variables are expanded.  (Other methods of quoting are generally uglier than this.)

Answer (score 4):

```
watch -n 5 "ls -lh club_prod.sql | awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Comment: Note that `$5` in this example will get eaten by the shell.

Comment: In my case using Ubuntu server I had to do print \$6 not sure if this is because linux now has more output on an ls -lh?  But if someone runs into this try 6 ;)

Answer (score 2):

For fast detailed growth watching of a file, every 0.1 second:

```
watch -n 0.1 "ls -l /mnt/some/file | awk '{print \$5}' | sed -re ' :rep ; s/([0-9])([0-9]{3})($|[^0-9])/\1,\2\3/ ; t rep '"
```

This will produce something like 62,673,539,072.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `watch` is correct, but the usage of `ls` I would avoid. I would recommend the usage of `stat` or `du`, but this depends on what you want.

- **`du`:** If you want the space occupied on your drive
- **`stat`:** If you want the number of bytes your file contains (how many bytes can I read from the file)

Imagine working with a compressed file system, or with processing sparse files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks ...

For both cases, the result would be:

```
$ watch -n 5 'stat --printf "%s\n" file'
$ watch -n 5 'du -B1 file'
```

Both results can actually be obtained in a single command with `stat`:

```
$ watch -n 5 'stat --printf "%s %b %B\n" file'
```

The product of the last two columns is the result of `du`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this like that:

```
while true; do
  du -s **file_or_directory**
 sleep **time_interval**
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash  
# Watch File Size and Growth  
# Author: Marcelo Pacheco - marcelo@m2j.com.br  
# Syntax: watchfilesize filetomonitor
nm="$1"  
while true  
do  
  sz=$(stat -c %s "$nm")  
  sleep 1m  
  sz1=$(stat -c %s "$nm")  
  echo Growth: $(((sz1-sz)/1024))KB/min Size: $((sz1/1024/1024))MB  
  sz=$sz1  
done
```